# Polynomial Regression Plot and 'newdata' Error

Tags: r, ggplot2, poly

I am trying to better understand why stat smooth won't plot my polynomial regression line unless my x variable (independent variable) is assigned as a value outside of the plot first (e.g. x <- dataset$Salary)

## Dataset

```
dataset <- tibble(Level = 1:10,
                  Salary = c(45000, 50000, 60000, 80000, 110000, 150000, 200000, 300000, 500000, 1000000))
```

## Initial plot that returns error

## Error:'newdata' had 80 rows but variables found have 10 rows

```
ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = Level, y = Salary)) +
  geom_point(color = "red") +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = dataset$Salary ~
      poly(dataset$Level, 3)) +
  ggtitle("Truth or Bluff (Linear Regression)") +
  xlab("Level ") +
  ylab("Salary") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

## The solution that worked

```
x <- dataset$Level

ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = Level, y = Salary)) +
  geom_point(color = "red") +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = dataset$Salary ~ 
      poly(x, 3)) +
  ggtitle("Truth or Bluff (Linear Regression)") +
  xlab("Level ") +
  ylab("Salary") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

## From my understanding

x <- dataset$Salary is no different from dataset$Salary aside from being contained in a Value. My only thought is it has to do with how poly() views x, a numeric vector vs. how it views dataset$Salary as an extracted vector. I

Other than that I would expect the same result, but that is not the case.

I also tried renaming x to t and it does exactly what the first graph did, so I don't understand why x is so significant if its just the name of the Value.

```
t <- dataset$Level

ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = Level, y = Salary)) +
  geom_point(color = "red") +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = dataset$Salary ~ 
      poly(t, 3)) +
  ggtitle("Truth or Bluff (Linear Regression)") +
  xlab("Level ") +
  ylab("Salary") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `formula` to `stat_smooth` uses mapped aesthetics, i.e. `x` and `y` (as you have mapped `x=Level, y=Salary`). If you had mapped `colour=SomeVariable` you'd have to use `colour` rather than `SomeVariable` also.

so

```
stat_smooth(..., formula=y ~ poly(x, 3))
```

---

The reason you are getting the warning

```
In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 80 rows but variables found have 10 rows
```

is that your data `dataset` has 10 rows. However `stat_smooth` is getting the fitted Y values of the model over 80 X points in order to get a smooth looking line, so these lengths don't match up.

The reason you *don't* get the error when you use `poly(x, 3)` in the formula is because this `x` resolves to the `x` of ggplot's constructed dataframe, rather than the global `x` you defined.

Similarly the reason you *do* get the error with `poly(t, 3)` is because `t` is not in ggplot's constructed dataframe so the next `t` on the search path is the global `t`.

Comment: Okay, so in other words the x that is being referenced is not the x I created outside the plot, but the x from the aes()?

Comment: @buttons yes, the formula looks in the mapped aesthetics first before going to the outside scope (global env)

Comment: Thank you that makes a lot of sense. Do you have any insights on what caused the error?

Comment: Updated the anwer to explain. If this answer solves your problem, please accept it.

Comment: Yes, that solves my error question too. Thank you so much for your help!